# Error extraño Warning : Undefined array key problema con variable GET

Tags: array, get, undefined

Tengo un error muy extraño en mi código PHP (Haber si alguien puede detectar el problema, tratare de ser claro):

**Comienzo:**

Hay una variable que vengo pasando por GET hace 2 enlaces atras (**Es un ID para consultar**)... (La muestro en verde).
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces pasa que llego hasta un formulario... Se supone que el formulario se envía hacía la misma pagina es decir; El usuario escribe el comentario le da click a enviar y pretendo que el comentario se guarde abajo uno de otro como muestro a continuación:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema es que cuando le das a "ENVIAR" me sale el siguiente error:

Warning
: Undefined array key "id" in
D:\xampp\htdocs\zona_dis_nes\errores\reporte_erroes.php
on line
25

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Yo asumo que lo que sucede es que al momento de presionarse el botón del formulario el archivo : **reporte_erroes** se recarga y tiene un conflicto** con la variable **"$GET_[id]"** que venía arrastrando desde antes ya que al recargarse la pagina pues ya no la reconoce y por eso me salta el error de **undefined array id**...

Sin embargo necesito ese **"$GET_[id]"** para colocarlo en mi consulta **sql** que es así:

$sql = "UPDATE  contenidones SET IdComentarios = '$_GET[comentario]' WHERE ID = '**$_GET[id]**' ";

¿Entonces pregunto: Alguien sabe como puedo evitar este error? (Todo lo tengo bien porque en el "WHERE ID =" si le paso un numero a mano si me actualiza los campos de la tabla, pero evidentemente necesito el **$_GET[id]**.

A continuación dejo mi código:

```
                include_once("../../_conexion_basededatos/database.php");


            $_GET['id'];

            echo "<div class='bg-white col-lg-7 col-sm-12'>";


            /* Si se presiona ENVIAR recogo lo que se ENVIO*/
            if (isset($_GET['comentario'])) {
                $sql = "UPDATE  contenidones SET IdComentarios = '$_GET[comentario]' WHERE ID = '$_GET[id]' ";

                $resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);



                if ($resultado == true) {
                    echo "<div class='bg-white col-lg-7 col-sm-12'>";
                    echo "Tu comentario se a enviado, gracias";
                    echo "</div>";
                } else {
                    echo "<div class='bg-white col-lg-7 col-sm-12'>";
                    echo "El comentario no pudo enviarse trata mas tarde";
                    echo "</div>";
                }
            }
            /* ---*/



            /* Aqui consulto una tabla COMENTARIOSNES (Esto es para probar, son los 3 comentarios que se ven en las imagenes*/
            $sql2 = "SELECT * FROM comentarios_nes ";
            $resultado2 = mysqli_query($conn, $sql2);
            $datos = [];
            while ($hileras = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultado2)) {
                $datos[] = $hileras;
            }
            /* ---*/

            /* Esto es el FORMULARIO*/
            echo   "<form>";
            echo       "<div class='form-group'>";
            echo           "<input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Deja un comentario' name='comentario'> ";
            echo           "<small id='emailHelp' class='form-text text-muted'>Comentario de no mas de 150 caracteres</small>";
            echo      "</div>";
            echo       "<button type='submit' class='btn btn-primary'  >Enviar</button>";
            echo      "</form>";
            /* ---*/

            /* Pinto los COMENTARIOS*/
            foreach ($datos as $i) {
                echo       "<div  class='bg-light mt-2' ><img src='/Imagenes/Iconos//icono_reporte.png' width=20 height=20> $i[Comentarios]</div>";
            }
            echo       "</div>";
            /* ---*/
```

Si alguien puede aportar algo gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero: los índices de tus arrays deben estar entre comillas simples o dobles. En lugar de, por ejemplo, `$_GET[comentario]` debes poner `$_GET['comentario']`

Segundo, en tu formulario no estás enviando la variable `id`, así que evidentemente el script no la va a encontrar en los subsecuentes envios. Añade un campo 'hidden' en tu formulario que contenga el valor de $_GET['id'] (siempre comprobando que el índice exista):

```
<input type='hidden' name='id' value='<?= isset($_GET['id']) ? $_GET['id'] : ''  ?>'>
```

Otra cosa: no necesitas poner el HTML dentro de sentencias `echo`. Se vuelve una pesadilla a la hora de hacer mantenimiento. En situaciones reales lo ideal es utilizar un motor de plantillas o al menos escribir HTML interpolando PHP donde sea necesario.

Comment: Jose A. Zapata me a funcionado, el problema era que cuando comparaba el ISSET para preguntar si existia el $_GET[id] estaba usando == en lugar de = ... 

Fue una tonteria, pero ahora el problema es que cuando pongo el $_GET[id] en el formulario me dice que se envió el comentario pero esto no ocurre así...

Me estoy fijando con un vardump y lo que me entrega el  $_GET[id] es esto  string(1) "1"    . Alguna idea de como quitarle ese STRING(1) ¿? (Es lo único que me falta)

Comment: Me respondo de nuevo: El metodo de José A. Zapata a resuelto totalmente el problema (Tenía cosas que no tenia que tener y todo el problema era enviar un input hidden) 

Sin embargo no comprendo porque al principio el "id" que enviaba por GET era un string y de la nada cambio a su valor (Eso no se como paso) Gracias.